# How to match the query from database and send it to order database?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am having problem in taking orders using php and maridb database. The codes are below.

The database table is:

```
Table emp_tasks
      workId(primary), mobile, workstatus, onlinestatus, last_task, job_cat

Table orders
      orderno(primary), user_mobile, emp_mobile, service_id,
                        order_date, order_status, lon, lat, service_cat
```

taking_orders.php

```
$jobCategory = $_GET["job_cat"];
$st=$con->prepare("select * from emp_tasks
          where onlinestatus=1 and workstatus=0 and job_cat=?
          order by workId");
$st->bind_param("s", $jobCategory );
$st->execute();
$rs=$st->get_result();

$row=$rs->fetch_assoc();
echo json_encode($row);


$st2=$con->prepare("insert into orders
       (user_mobile,emp_mobile,service_id,lon,lat,service_cat) 
        values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$st2->bind_param("ssidds", $_GET["mobile"], $row["mobile"],
                           $_GET["service_id"], $_GET["lon"], 
                           $_GET["lat"], $_GET["service_cat"]);
$st2->execute();

$dt=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$st3=$con->prepare("update emp_tasks set workstatus=1,last_task=?
        where mobile=? and job_cat = ? 
order by workId");
$st3->bind_param("sss", $dt, $row["mobile"], $jobCategory);
$st3->execute();


$st4=$con->prepare("select emp_mobile, max(orderno) as orderno 
       from orders where emp_mobile=?
       group by emp_mobile" );
$st4->bind_param("s", $row["mobile"]);
$st4->execute();
```

All the things are inserted in order table successfully but the `emp_mobile` from the table `emp_tasks` remains blank and also the `job_cat` is not matching when its number is more than one in the table.

The `user_mobile`, `service_id` etc are taken from other table.

Only focus on `emp_mobile` from order table.

Comment: I Think You Need To Bind Them Together With Foreign Key

Comment: How are the tables "related"?